# What is the best practice to validate a form if I need each numerical value to be checked mathematically before the main function starts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The user's input must look like "value1,value2,value3,valu4..." and value[i]-value[i-1] must be greater than, say, 0.5. Minimum value is 0, maximum is 100. For example, "0,5,10.5,20" is OK. My basic code is

```
$('.click').click(function () {
    var flag = true;
    var str = $('input').val();
    var arr = str.split(',');
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        jQuery.each(arr, function (i) {
            if (arr[i] < 0 || arr[i] > 100 || arr[i + 1] - arr[i] < 0.5) {
                flag = false
            }
        });
        if (flag) {
        //main function must never start before we complete that check on all the values
            alert("OK, our function starts now. Your input is " + str)
        } else {
            alert("Please, check your input: " + str)
        }
    }
});
```

and this seems to work, but I'm not sure: maybe I'm missing something.
My question is how to force my main function not to start before the array check is finished. Is there a chance for it to start before all numbers in that `arr` are checked? And maybe there's no need to create that flag, then what would you do to perform this kind of validation?

Comment: on first inspection this seems fine. You are validating each item and setting a flag based on that. you may want to add a return=false; so that it exits the loop the first time flag is set, rather than continuing. You could also consider seperating this loop into its own function, and use the function call to display your alerts rather than the flag. But if it works...

Comment: what are you referring to when you say your 'main' function?

Comment: @lukeocom: yes, I also thought that we have to stop our checking as soon as we encounter a "bad" value, but I don't know how the safe code should look like. And "main function" is the one that is guaranteed to never start before the entire input has been checked (in this simple demo case, it's `alert("OK")`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a re-write of what you have, splitting the main algorithm into its own function, and using its return value to display your alerts. Obviously I havent been able to test it as I dont have your web page, but with a bit of luck it should work...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.click').click(function() {
        var str = $('input').val();
        if (inputCheck(str)) {
            //if true
            alert("OK, our function starts now. Your input is " + str);
        } else {
            alert("Please, check your input: " + str);
        }
    });
});

function inputCheck(str) {
    var arr = str.split(','),
        flag = false;
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        jQuery.each(arr, function(i) {
            if (arr[i] < 0 || arr[i] > 100 || arr[i + 1] - arr[i] < 0.5) {
                flag = false;
                return false;
                //exit loops
            } else
                flag = true;
        });
        //end each
    }//end if
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Need to replace `var str = $(this).val()` by `var str = $('input').val()`... okay, thanks, I'll dig into this...

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any way the execution path could pass the check. However you probably want to check against non-numerical values too and you *can* get rid of that nested function

```
$('.click').click(function () {
    var str = $('input').val();
    var arr = str.split(',');
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i]<0 || arr[i]>100 || arr[i+1]-arr[i]<0.5 || !jQuery.isNumeric(arr[i])) {
                return alert("Please, check your input: " + str);
            }
        }
        main(str);
    }
});

function main(str) { // Just so that this *main function* exists ;)
    alert("OK, our function starts now. Your input is " + str);
}
```

Comment: I remember the non-numerical value situation, but I skipped this logic just to simplify the example. So, if `main(str)` won't start if we received a return from the loop, then this code is okay